# how parse a underscore from a path in python

Tags: python

I have a question on removing a underscore from a path.

Here is the example below:

```
C:\\Users\\Me\\level1\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level6\\level7\\level8\\test_one.txt
```

How do I remove the underscore and move up a level?

I need my output to become:

```
C:\\Users\\Me\\level1\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level6\\level7\\testone.txt
```

I have this so far

```
var = "C:\\Users\\Me\\level1\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level6\\level7\\level8\\test_one.txt"

split_path = os.path.split(os.path.split(var)[0])

print split_path
```

output below:

```
('C:\\level1\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level7\\level8', 'test_one.txt')
```

Comment: "parse" or "remove"? Two different things. I looks like you mean "remove the underscore". Is this correct?

Comment: I want to remove correct

Comment: Use `dirname` to remove a level from the directory. Use `str.replace` to replace the underscore with empty-string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're right to use `os.path.split`, and you also want [`os.path.dirname`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname). How about:

```
var = "C:\\Users\\Me\\level1\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level6\\level7\\level8\\test_one.txt"
base_path, filename = os.path.split(var)
# Sort the underscore out
new_filename = filename.replace('_', '')
# Go one level up from base_path
new_base_path = os.path.dirname(base_path)

output = os.path.join(new_base_path, new_filename)
print(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import os.path

path = "C:\\Users\\Me\\level1\\level2\\level3\\level4\\level5\\level6\\level7\\level8\\test_one.txt"

new_parent = os.path.split(os.path.split(path)[0])[0]
new_child = os.path.split(path)[1].replace('_', '')
new_path = os.path.join(new_parent, new_child)

print new_path
```